# How to Explode PySpark column having multiple dictionaries in one row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with one column having multiple dictionaries:

| id | result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'key1':'a', 'key2':'b'}, {'key1':'d', 'key2':'e'}, {'key1':'m', 'key2':'n'} |
| 2 | {'key1':'r', 'key2':'s'}, {'key1':'t', 'key2':'u'} |

I need the final output as:

| id | key1 | key2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b |
| 1 | d | e |
| 1 | m | n |
| 2 | r | s |
| 2 | t | u |

And planning to explode this twice to get the results.

Although, The column `result` is of `StringType()` and therefore I am unable to explode it using the `explode` function:

```
df.withColumn("output", explode(col("result")))
```

Error:

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`result`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string;
> 'Project [result#9651, explode(result#9651) AS output#9660]
> +- Relation[result#9651] json

Please help on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the `result` column to an array of struct structure using the `from_json` function, and then expand it using the `inline` function.

```
json_schema = """
    array<struct<key1:string,key2:string>>
"""
df = df.withColumn('result', F.from_json(F.concat(F.lit('['), 'result', F.lit(']')), json_schema)) \
    .selectExpr('id', 'inline(result)')
df.show(truncate=False)
```